# AWK performance tune for writing multiple files

Tags: performance, awk, cpu, gawk

```
gawk -v ff=${fileB} '
    /^1017/ { print $0 >> ff; next; }
    !(/^#/||/^1016/||/^1018/||/^1013/||/^1014/||/^1013/||/^1014/) {
        f=substr($0,11,2)".csv"; print $0 >>"../../" f;
    }
' ${csvfiles}
```

The big file contains various 20 million lines.and we have to  read each line if it starts with 1017 it will be printed in fileB irrespective of line content
if it starts not starting with the skip list above(`1016,1013..`) it will be written in file, where the filename is taken from the line content. for example the line 
`1010,abcdefg,123453,343,3434,` written in fg.csv. we do substring and take the fg from the second column.

The problem is the performance is like 35k lines per second. is it possible to make it faster?

```
sample input 
 Exclusion List 1016 1013 ..

 Include line number 1010,1017...

1016,abcdefg,123453,343,3434,

1010,abcdefg,123453,343,3434,

1017,sdfghhj,123453,343,3434,

1034,zxczcvf,123453,343,3434,

1055,zxczcfg,123453,343,3434,

sample output 

fileB.csv

1017,sdfghhj,123453,343,3434,

fg.csv

055,zxczcfg,123453,343,3434,

vf.csv

1034,zxczcvf,123453,343,3434,
```

Comment: split the big file, run chunks in parallel and `cat` the results into one file.

Comment: [edit] your question and use the editor's `{}` button to format your sample input/output. Also be specific about which numbers you want to exclude and make sure your sample input/output and code reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gawk -v ff="$fileB" '
    !/^(#|10(1[6834]|24|55))/{ print > (/^1017/ ? ff : "../../" substr($0,20,2) ".csv") }
' "$csvfiles"
```

This MAY speed things up if all the time is being spent on file opens/closes:

```
awk '!/^(#|10(1[6834]|24|55))/{print substr($0,20,2), $0}' "$csvfiles" |
sort -t ' ' |
awk -v ff="$fileB" '
    {
        curr = substr($0,1,2)
        str  = substr($0,3)
        if ( index(str,"1017") == 1 ) {
            out = ff
        }
        else if ( curr != prev ) {
            close(out)
            out = "../../" curr ".csv"
            prev = curr
        }
        print str > out
    }
' "$csvfiles"
```

I'm really not sure if it'll be any faster but it might be due to the simpler regexp at least it's concise.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, I got more line start number like 1024,1055 etc , is there a way to change the regex to accept last two digit of number ?

Comment: looks like these are complete fields.  Equality check should be faster than regex.

Comment: @karakfa Could be but it sounds like there's a lot of them so idk if, for example, 20 string comparisons would be faster than 1 regexp comparison plus if you don't refer to a field in the script then awk doesn't do field-splitting when it reads each record so you save time there with a regexp comparison on the record vs a string comparison on a field.

Comment: Yes, I didn't consider field-splitting, which may change the dynamics.  On the other hand equality checks will be short-circuited, so the average comparison will be less than the worst case and can be optimized if distribution of keys is given.

Comment: Right, my vote is to leave it as an exercise for the OP :-). I suspect all the file writing (and possibly management behind the scenes of opening/closing them) is probably the lions share of where the time is being spent anyway rather than the comparisons.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes that's my doubt. We have 257 files. This will open a file and go to the end of the file and it needs to append line from big file finally close it.This would happen for all 20 million lines. So i think it takes time on that.

Comment: It doesn't open/close them one output line at a time but rather closes them as some threshold for max concurrently open files is exceeded and then opens again when necessary. I updated my answer with an approach that may help...